# How can I get user history Display Names from Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)?

Tags: dataexplorer, displayname-attribute

Users may change their ***Display Name***.

However, in existing comments, the 'pinging' activity may have occurred before the Display Name was modified, which makes it impossible for me to konw who this comment interacted with.

For example, the 'pinging' `@OneKitten` of comment of post: [Why are we getting yearling badges for a site that is 1 day old?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250014/why-are-we-getting-yearling-badges-for-a-site-that-is-1-day-old#comment54_250014).

> How can I obtain the historical Display Names of some users in batches from **Stack Exchange Data Explorer** (SEDE)?

I trid to use SEDE to `select` the corresponding infroamtion, code as:

```
# here PK='id' and table='users'

select c.Table_Name
     , case 
       when ##PK:string?id## = c.column_name then concat(c.column_name,' (PK)') 
       else c.column_name 
       end as column_name
     , data_type
     , is_nullable
     , coalesce(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
             , numeric_precision
             , datetime_precision) as [Length/precision]
 --     ,*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns c
where c.table_name = ##table:string?posts##
order by ordinal_position
```

result as:

| Table_Name | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| Users | Id (PK) |
| Users | ... |
| Users | DisplayName |
| Users | AccountId |

[more Infromation schema for a Users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pLlh.png)

> It it worth noting that there is no inforamtion here about the historical Display Names.

> How can I get user history Display Names from Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)?

Comment: You may not be able to. Some data isn't available via the API.

Comment: @Ouroborus Is there any other way to obtain their historical Display Names based on the users' ID?

Comment: Doubt it. The usual reason some of that data is restricted is to prevent things like stalking or retaliation.

Comment: @Ouroborus I there enough evidence to prove this? If so, then I give up.

Comment: The entire available API is documented [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). There's nothing that even hints at a display name history being exposed.